# Undesired loop in assembly

Tags: assembly

I've been messing with this code for awhile now and I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to get 2 different triangles to print based on a users input and so far I have only gotten the first triangle to print correctly.

For instance, If a user enters 4 the output should be like so:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *

* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

My code produces the first triangle correctly but for the second it adds one and outputs like this

```
 * * * * *
 * * * *
 * * *
 * *
```

My question is how do I get the correct output

```
org 100h


.data
Input db "Enter size of the triangle between 2 to 9: $" ;String to prompt the user
Size dw ?               ; variable to hold size of triangle


.code
Main proc
Start:
Mov ah, 09h
Mov dx, offset input ;prompts user for input
int 21h

mov ah, 01h
int 21h; takes user input

sub al, '0'

mov ah, 0   ;blank top half of ax reigster

mov size, ax ; we use ax instead of al because we used dw instead of db
mov cx, ax ; copy size into variable size and cx reigster     

mov bx, 1                    

call newline


lines:                 ; outer loop for number of lines
push cx
mov cx,bx





stars:                 ; inner loop to print stars

mov ah, 02h   
mov dl, '*'
int 21h


loop stars

inc bx

call newline
pop cx


loop lines
call newline  




; second triangle   

mov cx, size 


lines2:  

push cx
mov cx,bx





stars2:
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h

loop stars2

 dec bx

 call newline
 pop cx
loop lines2 
;end 



call newline
mov cx, size
; third triangle   
mov cx, size

lines3:
push cx
mov cx,bx

main endp   


proc newline
mov ah, 02h        ; go to a new line after input
mov dl, 13
int 21h
mov dl, 10
int 21h

ret ;returns back


newline endp

end main
```

Comment: So, have you tried adding a `dec bx` at `; second triangle` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first triangle, BX is one number above the desired, so, just above the `lines2:` label add the line `dec bx` :

```
.
.
.
; second triangle   

mov cx, size 
dec bx         ;<========================

lines2:  

push cx
mov cx,bx
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `dec bx` from line after `loop stars2` to next line after `lines2:`.